# insert debug env json propety VSCode

Tags: json, go, visual-studio-code

I want to configure go debug env json properties like following

```
DEV_PROP=
'{
 "run": "app.sh",  
 "server_port": "8081",
 "app_url":"http://localhost:3000"
}'
```

Ive tried to enter the following to the env but I got error

```
"configurations": [

    {
        "name": "Launch",
        "type": "go",
        "request": "launch",
        "mode": "debug",
        "remotePath": "",
        "port": 2345,
        "host": "127.0.0.1",
        "program": "${fileDirname}",
        "env": {

        },
```

when I insert the DEV_PROP to the env object I got lots of error, ive tried to play with quotas without success, any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try this way?

```
{
    "name": "Launch",
    "type": "go",
    "request": "launch",
    "mode": "debug",
    "remotePath": "",
    "port": 2345,
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "program": "${fileDirname}",
    "env": {
        "run": "app.sh",  
        "server_port": "8081",
        "app_url":"http://localhost:3000"
    },
```

As shown here http://techbrij.com/visual-studio-code-tasks-debugging

Also by convention environment variables should be all UPPER_CASE as shown here https://stackoverflow.com/a/673940/6314736

So it should look like that:

```
{
    "name": "Launch",
    "type": "go",
    "request": "launch",
    "mode": "debug",
    "remotePath": "",
    "port": 2345,
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "program": "${fileDirname}",
    "env": {
        "RUN": "app.sh",  
        "SERVER_PORT": "8081",
        "APP_URL":"http://localhost:3000"
    }
}
```

Also if you want to have separate launch for dev environment just copy this object and change "name" property to whatever you like. It should be in Configuration array.

**EDIT**
As [Adrian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7426/adrian) pointed out, my answer to this question was wrong.
The correct answer is to escape double quotes with backslashes.
`"env":{ 
"DEV_PROP":"\"run\":\"app.sh\",\"server_port\":\"8081\",\"app_url\":\"http
://localhost:3000\"}"
}`

I've tested it and it works fine.
[Picture for proof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XAe5D.png)

Comment: Not 100% sure but judging by the way the question is written, they want a single environment variable `DEV_PROP` whose value is the JSON they gave.

Comment: oh yeah, you are probably right. Then maybe escape quotes with backslashes
`"DEV_PROP":"
{
 \"run\": \"app.sh\",  
 \"server_port\": \"8081\",
 \"app_url\":\"http://localhost:3000\"
}"`